# How to re-present modalViewController on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, window, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

My app has two windows, *mainWindow* (for almost all views) and *loginWindow* (just for login view).
When `applicationDidEnterBackground` I switch *mainWindow* with *loginWindow*:

```
[self.loginWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
[self.mainWindow setHidden:YES];
```

When I came back in app the *loginWindow* with its views is shown. That works just fine.

However I have a problem with `modalView` presentation in *mainWindow*. 
After `applicationDidEnterBackground` windows are switched again. After going back to mainWindow the modalView is not visible.

Method `self.modalViewController` gives me the exact `modalView` that was presented earlier, but is not visible anymore.

I've tried to show this modalView again with no luck like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.modalViewController animated:NO];
```

How can I "re-present" this hidden modalView again?

Comment: Is self.modalView a view property?

Comment: @RohanKapur: nope it's not. But that's not the problem. In anyway a get a reference to the right instance of modally presented object. I just need to some kind a represent it again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need some logic here. Like Crio stated, dismiss it when entering the background, but remember it in a property or smth. else.

```
// applicationDidEnterBackground
self.savedModalViewController = self.modalViewController;
[self.mainWindow dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

// after login but before presenting the mainWindow again
[self.mainWindow presentModalViewController:self.savedModalViewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: I've already thought about that but was looking for a nicer and simpler solution. Maybe this is the only one. Thanks!

Comment: instead of switching windows, you could just exchange the `rootViewController` of the `mainWindow` with the `mainController` and the `loginController`.. perhaps the modal view would stay in place in that case.

Comment: It doesn't work either. Modal hides in both cases. By the way. Why should I switch rootViewController instead of windows? What is advantage/disadvantages of doing each... ?

Comment: iOS apps normally just use one keyWindow. Its quite expensive to create windows and also to switch between them. But if you don't experience any delays (test old devices), you're fine. (But you're memory footprint will also be higher, when you use two windows)

Comment: Thanks. I'll stick with one window.

Answer (score 0):

If your showing the "modalView" modally, then on `applicationDidEnterBackground` dismiss the modal view:

```
[self.mainWindow dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

and then the modal should work fine.

Comment: If I dismiss modalView than it's not presented anymore. But I don't want to loose this view and want it to stay presented until I close it manually.

Comment: is there a reason your leaving it presented if your, by the sounds of it, going to make the user log in again ?

Comment: It's actually not a login screen but some kind a "first screen" that user sees every time...